# Gradle: common resource dependency for multiple java projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm developing a multi-module project with gradle/intellij-idea, and here is the structure of my project home:

```
project/
  sub-project-1
    /main/resources
  sub-project-2
    /main/resources
  data
    /main/resources
    /test/resources
```

As you can see I have multiple sub-projects (all java), how can I make them depend on some common resources (the "data" project, which contains no code but only resources), as well as their own separate resources?

Also it's best that the intellij-idea can pick up these dependencies with JetGradle automatically (JetGradle do just fine picking up the default gradle java project dependencies within each sub project).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One solution is to apply the Java plugin also to the `data` project, and then use regular project dependencies (e.g. `dependencies { runtime project(":data") }`). However, this would require a bit of effort to prevent shipping the test resources.

Another solution is not to make `data` a Gradle project but literally include its resource directories in the other two projects (`sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir "../data/main/resources"; sourceSets.test.resources.srcDir "../data/test/resources"`).

Answer (score 21):

The approach I took was to use project reference

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs += [
                project(':data').sourceSets.main.resources
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Tested with Gradle7 and it still works. Tested with java-library plugin.

Comment: dude you are such a damn life saver. I was trying for hours to get a file to load across two modules without duplicating it but no matter where I put it, what I named it, or how I loaded it from the classpath whenever execution switched from one module to another gradle module I always got `FileNotFoundException`. This fixed the issue!

Comment: I get a stack overflow when trying this. Bounces between

    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.getSrcDirTrees(DefaultSourceDirectorySet.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.doGetSrcDirTrees(DefaultSourceDirectorySet.java:141)

Comment: @ToddiusZho have you created a cyclical import loop? Where project 1 imports project 2 and project 2 imports project 1? Hierarchy is extremely important in gradle it's easy to create cyclical loops.

Comment: No, something about the way subprojects are declared, each subproject has the right name and projectDir, yet all their sourceSets are exactly the same as the parent project! So I had to use the subprojects Closure to dynamically reconstruct their srcDirs back to src/main/resources and src/test/resources, relative to their projectDir.

Comment: I think this answer is now outdated. As per the latest gradle version, `sourceSets` doesn't exist on the `Project` type.

Comment: @kapad it's not outdated, still working on latest Gradle

Comment: Yes, this is still working! I would due expect Gradle can support such a behavior in the dependency section ‍♂️

Answer (score 6):

You need to choose the project which will hold your resources. All the other projects that require those resources, will add them to the `resources` component of the sourceSets.

```
sourceSets {
    data {
        resources {
            srcDir "${project(':data').projectDir}/src/main/resources"
            include "your_pattern_here**"
        }
    }
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs += [ data.resources ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the "data" under "sourceSets" the same or differnent ":data" ?  GAAAAA.  My kingdom for questions that don't use KEYWORDS.  "sub-project-1", "sub-project-2", and "myshared" would have been ambiguity free.

Comment: I see it now.  For future readers, I think it can be anything.  Here is use "peanutbutter" to show how it can be anything.   sourceSets {
    peanutbutter {
        resources {.  and  srcDirs += [ peanutbutter.resources ]

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I figured it out. It's actually pretty simple. Just treat the "data" folder as another project and add dependency declarations to sub projects will do the trick. For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile project (':data')
    testCompile project (':data')
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, 
I want to do pretty much the same thing. did you actually create the :data project as a gradle project? if so ,could you share your build.gradle please?

Answer (score 3):

And here is version for Kotlin DSL - to sync all resources from :data module to root and all sub-modules build/resources folders:

```
// Synchronizing resources from :data module to project root: build/resources
synchronizeSharedResources()

subprojects {
    // Synchronizing resources from :data module to all submodules: build/resources
    synchronizeSharedResources()
}

fun Project.synchronizeSharedResources() {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources.srcDir(project(":data").sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs)
        }
        test {
            resources.srcDir(project(":data").sourceSets["test"].resources.srcDirs)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate where you will put synchronizeSharedResources function and subprojects block?

Answer (score 0):

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs += [
                '../sub-project-1/src/main/resources',
                '../sub-project-2/src/main/resources',
                '../data/src/main/resources'
            ]
        }
    }

    test {
        resources {
            srcDir '../data/src/test/resources'
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had another problem with resources in multi-module project, may be it will helpful for somebody.

I have two independent modules:

```
- database (contains migrations for whole project)
- main (contains business logic(controllers, services and etc))
```

Also I use Spring-Boot 2 in my project.

I have integration tests in `main` and before test is started I need to create schema and tables in DB. But all my migrations (use `Flyway` for migration control) in `database` module. Path for migration is `src/main/resources/db/migrations`.

As a result I need to have all migrations in `/test/resources` in order to start tests. Of course, I don't want to duplicate migrations in `main` module and I found this solution. I need to add these lines in files in `main` module.

`builde.gradle`

```
dependencies { 
   testImplementation "com.example.module:database:$dbMigrationVersion"
}
```

`application-test.yml`

```yaml
spring:
  flyway:
     locations: classpath:/BOOT-INF/classes/db/migration
```

After these lines all your migrations from  `database`  module will be in `main` module classpath (in our case for *test* profile). And flyway can execute them before starting tests.

Answer (score 0):

If all your projects are java projects and you apply `java` plugin to them you can just do the following. Assuming your directory structure you could do :

```
def dataMainResourcesPath = rootProject.projectDir.path + '/data/main/resources'
def dataTestResourcesPath = rootProject.projectDir.path + '/data/test/resources'

subprojects.each {
    it.sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs += dataMainResourcesPath
    it.sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs += dataTestResourcesPath
}
```

in your root `build.gradle`.

Comment: This works (as well as the other variants of this approach), but will cause issues in IDEs - for example IntelliJ starts complaining about "duplicate content roots detected". See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210311/Multiple-modules-with-shared-content-root-error-after-upgrade-20183-20191 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6745/Cannot-define-two-identical-content-roots-in-different-module-within-a-single-project