# how gradle add code and resources from another sub-project to the sub-project

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-fabric

i have a minecraft fabric mod project

this is its struct

```
airgame-api-parent:
    airgame-api-common:
    airgame-api-client:
    airgame-api-server:
    airgame-api-all:
```

> Initially, i build them as a single project, but with the increase of code and function, i added some another depend into my project. such as `mysql-connector` and `HikariCP`.
> its only needed in server side because the client does not need to connect my sql.
> but `mysql-connector` is too big. it caused my jar file size increase to 4MB+ from 100KB+.
> I think it's unbearable.

So I disassembled my project.

the project `airgame-api-common` is universal environment code: it can be running with client and server.

the project `airgame-api-client` is client side only code. it just can be running with client. it depend with `api-common`.

the project `airgame-api-server` is server side only code. it just can be running with server. it depend with `api-common` too.

the `api-server` include some server-side code. example as `mysql-connector` and `HikariCP`.

and finally, the `api-all` include all code of `api-common`, `api-client` and `api-server`. In this way, I don't need to import `api-client` and `api-server` at the same time when coding other projects. (Actually, I can't do that because `api-client` and `api-server` used the same `mod_id`. If I import them, when I execute the test, the running environment will contain both dependencies, and then crash due to `mod_id` conflict.)

okay, first i try to use `api project(":airgame-api-common")` in the `api-client`, but it now work, other project that depend `api-client` still can not see `api-common`. i guess may plugin `fabric-loom` changed gradle's build or depend logic.

the `fabric-loom` [docs](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/documentation:fabric_loom) say that i need use `modApi`, i tried, but it look like cant be use to import self sub-project.

OK, I'm sorry to say a lot of things that have nothing to do with the problem, but I just want to show that I've done my best to solve the problem.

**So now I guess there's one way left: add classpath and resources from `api-common` to other projects before gradle starts compiling code. I think modifying `build.gradle` can do it, but I don't know what to do.**

I tried to read gradle's documentation, but I really didn't know much about the software, so I couldn't find much useful information. Can someone tell me?

I need the `api-client` compile file have both its own code and `api-common` code, and the `api-common` code needs to be visible to the projects that depend on the `api-client`.(This is also required for `api-server` and `api-all`. But I think if you teach me to configure `api-client`, I should be able to configure others.)

Finally, my English is not very good, but I try my best to express my intention. I don't mean any harm to anyone. If I offend you, please forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer in another answer: [Gradle: common resource dependency for multiple java projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136214)

its

```
sourceSets.main {
    java.srcDirs += [
        project(':api-common').sourceSets.main.java,
        project(':api-common-server').sourceSets.main.java
    ]
    resources.srcDirs += [
        project(':api-common').sourceSets.main.resources,
        project(':api-common-server').sourceSets.main.resources
    ]
}
```